# Beta Newsletters Don't Match the Beta Theme

Tags: feature-request, design, newsletter, beta-sites

The newsletters for beta sites don't match the main theme of the beta sites. For example, compare the beta site theme and the beta site newsletter.

> [image: Beta Site Theme]
>   *Look at those curves...*

---

> [image: Beta Site Newsletter]
>   *It's all blocky... Like Stack Overflow...*

So to remedy this ***terrible*** situation, I propose a beta newsletter that is more in *sync* with the beta site. Something similar to this.

> [image: Proposed Beta Site Newsletter]
>   *That's better!*

---

If you noticed, I also removed the *x votes* text as it clutters the screen forcing the user descriptions onto two lines most of the time. It also provides no useful information for a user who is reading these questions. I don't need vote statistics to tell me this question is a good one. That is the point of the newsletter, to choose the good questions for me.

---

**Additional Information**

Just for the designers I applied a border radius of 15 pixels to `table table` (CSS selector) and to the tags.

---

**Update**

I just got the newsletter for [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) today and nothing has changed. I would love it if I could get a comment with a status update of some sorts. Maybe have this retagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), or [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).